# How to add checkboxes for each records showing Contracts of Account according to hierarchy on VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, account, contracts

Account is one object and Contract is another object.

I want to show Contracts of all Child Accounts on Ultimate Parent Account.

Below is the code for same.

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class AccountHierarchyController {
public Account acc { get; private set; }
public List<Account> accountList { get; private set; }
public ApexPages.StandardController controller { get; private set; }
  public AccountHierarchyController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.acc = (Account)controller.getRecord();
    this.accountList = new List<Account>();

    Account baseAccount = [SELECT Id, 
                           ParentId, 
                           Name,
                           Parent.Name,
                           (SELECT ContractNumber,SBQQ__ActiveContract__c,StartDate,Contract_renewed__c FROM Contracts),
                           (SELECT Id, Name FROM ChildAccounts)
                           FROM Account 
                           WHERE Id = :acc.id];
    accountList.add(baseAccount);

    // Traverse the hierarchy downwards
    Set<Id> accountsToQuery = new Map<Id, Account>(baseAccount.ChildAccounts).keySet();
    while (accountsToQuery.size() > 0) {
        List<Account> thisLevelAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Parent.Name,
                                           (SELECT ContractNumber,SBQQ__ActiveContract__c,StartDate,Contract_renewed__c FROM Contracts),
                                           (SELECT Id, Name FROM ChildAccounts)
                                           FROM Account
                                           WHERE Id IN :accountsToQuery];
        accountsToQuery = new Set<Id>();

        for (Account a : thisLevelAccounts) {
            // Add this Account (with its Contracts) to the list.
            accountList.add(a);

            // Add this Account's children to the query for the next level.
            for (Account child : a.ChildAccounts) {
                accountsToQuery.add(child.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Vf Page**

```
<apex:page title="Contract" standardController="Account" extensions="AccountHierarchyController">
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
    var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){
        if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){
            inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
        }
   }
}
</script>    
<apex:form >
<apex:outputPanel id="cont">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Contracts">


        <apex:repeat value="{! accountList }" var="a">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{! a.Name + IF(NOT(ISBLANK(a.ParentId)), ' (child of ' + a.Parent.Name + ')', '') }">

             <apex:commandLink value="New Contract" action="{!newContract}" target="_parent"  styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" />

             <apex:commandLink value="Renew Contract" action="{!newContract}" target="_parent"  styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" />

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! a.Contracts }" var="con"  title="Contract">
                 <apex:column > 
                  <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox id="chkbox" onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                    </apex:facet>   
                  <apex:inputCheckbox id="inputId" />    
                 </apex:column>  
                 <apex:column HeaderValue="Action" width="60"> 
                    <apex:commandLink value="Edit" action="{!editContract}" target="_parent"><apex:param value="{!con.id}" name="contractId"/> </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Contract Number"><apex:outputLink value="/{!con.id}" target="_blank">{!con.ContractNumber}</apex:outputLink> </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!con.SBQQ__ActiveContract__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!con.StartDate}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!con.EndDate}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!con.Contract_renewed__c}" /> 


                <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="{!(ISNULL(a.Contracts))}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>       
</apex:page>
```

I want to add checkbox in front of each contract so that I can select one record or multiple records at a time.. how to achieve this??

Comment: Can you provide the full code of your Apex class?

Comment: I have modified the code .. and its working fine now.. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Apex controller appears to be missing a `class` declaration and all of its member variable declarations. What you have here is only a constructor, which Apex is not expecting to see outside the scope of a class.

You'll need to write the class definition and the declarations of the instance variables `acc` and `accountList`.

Comment: It worked..!! Thanks

Comment: if I want to add checkbox in front of each contract so that I select the records.. how to achieve this??